# In an AlertDialog, how to set the image on the top

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am  working on a coding exercise,which is about AlertDialog. In the Dialog, I hope the image or view can be placed on the top of the dialog,like a header,but it goes to the bottom.

The XML code:

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/star"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text=" choose your sex"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Activity code:

```
private void showSingleDialog() {
 LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
 final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_solo, null);

 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 builder.setView(view);

 final String[] sex = {
  "male",
  "felmale",
  "unknow",
  "guess"
 };
 builder.setSingleChoiceItems(sex, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "your choice is:" + sex[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   dialog.dismiss();
  }
 });

 builder.show();
}
```

I tried to place the builder.setView(view) in different place, it still go to the bottom.
Is there any hints for me? Thanks a lot

p.s Sorry for my poor English, I attached the image here[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Lkq.png)

I hope the little Star and "choose your sex" go on the top

Comment: Hey can u show me your entire layout file. Maybe you just need to restructure your layout file

Comment: Sorry for response late, this xml code here is the entire view  including an image view and a textView in a LinearLayout. I added the view to this SingleChoice AlertDialog as a header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can achieve the same view with drawable and title methods:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final String[] array = {"male","felmale","unknow","guess"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_star);
    builder.setTitle("Choose your sex")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(array, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    sex = array[i];
                    //handle on click 
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

I achieved the same view like this:

[image: Dialog with custom title]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I set android:onClick for the button and I can simply run the "public void dialog "to call the dialog, but  how to call this custom dialog ?

Comment: I have updated my answer have a look at it @user10350198